# PowerShell registering multiple scheduled jobs

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've managed to piece together a Powershell script that when run asks for a Server and date/time when the server will be rebooted.

I'm a bit lost on making the script schedule multiple servers for reboot.  Can it be as simple as removing the `param $server` and do a simple `$servers = GC TextFile.txt` + `foreach ($server in $servers)`?  I could name each scheduled job as the server name but how can I clean that up after execution?

Additionally, there has to be an easier way to remove a previously registered Powershell scheduled job than the frankencode I've put together below.

```
Function ScheduleReboot{
 [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
HelpMessage="ServerName goes here")]
 [string]$server,
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
  HelpMessage="Enter a Date/Time 07-28-15 16:00 For July 28th, 2015 at 4:00 PM")]
  [ValidatePattern('(?#Enter MM-dd-YY HH:MM 24hr clock)\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}[:]\d{2}')]
  $date)
 if($env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "x86")
 {
set-alias ps64 "$env:windir\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
ps64 -command "IF(Test-Path -Path C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\RebootOnce2){Remove-Item -Force -Path C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\RebootOnce2}" #End 64 bit powershell.
 }
Else
{
 Get-ScheduledJob | Unregister-ScheduledJob
}
$user = Get-Credential -UserName $env:USERNAME -Message "UserName/password for scheduled Reboot"
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -once -at $date
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create("D:\Scripts\Scheduled-Reboot-Single.ps1 -server $server | Out-File -Force \\SysLogServer\d$\scripts\$server-Reboot.log")
Register-ScheduledJob -Name RebootOnce2 -Credential $user -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock $script
}#end function.
```

Comment: You might take a look at the [this article](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/3865/powershell-reminder-jobs/) for an alternative approach. It uses the `Start-Job` commandlet instead of a full blown scheduled job but it's suited for those one time things you like to run.

Comment: Why are you launching a whole new Powershell process just to test for a file, and delete it if it exists?

Comment: It's launching the x64 Powershell console to delete a file from `C:\Windows\System32` in the event the script is run from an x86 console.  Perhaps this script is best posted on CodeReview?